# Socket in javascript

Tags: javascript, sockets

please what is different

var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8181');

var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8181/**websession**');

what is ( **Websession**  )

Comment: It's a URL. The server is free to do with it what it wants

Answer (score 1):

`websession` is just the endpoint the websocket will connect to. It's just like normal HTTP servers or REST services: You can have multiple endpoints on one server, like:

- `ws://localhost:8181/customers`
- `ws://localhost:8181/prices`
- `ws://localhost:8181/items`

... and so on. (This is just an example and does not necessarily make sense for a specific use case.) In old-style HTTP, you could image them as different directories on the same server, possibly offering very different contents.

In order to use the socket correctly, you have to know your desired endpoint and use it when creating the socket. So it depends on the server whether `ws://localhost:8181` or `ws://localhost:8181/websession` is correct (or even both of them, depending on the purpose of the individual endpoint). It's generally a good practice to give the endpoint a meaningful name, so the first one would be discouraged.

As the application seems to be running on your `localhost`, you should take a look at the server running at port `8181` to find out the endpoints offered. And you could possibly get used to websockets, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) is one of many possible starting points.